# New to java, and need someone to show me where I'm missing a return statement in my Java homework program?

Tags: java

The program instructs to have the user input Minutes and convert it to Hours and days, then output all results this is the third time I have redone my program and get the same error, missing return statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MinutesConversion
{
  public static Void main(String[] args)
  {

   // declare constant here
    final int MINUTES_DAY= 1440;
    final int MINUTES_HOUR= 60;
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);  

// input minutes
    int minutes;

//output statement
    System.out.println("Enter number of minutes:");
    minutes=scanner.nextInt();

// Calculate number of hours and days 
    int hours=minutes/MINUTES_HOUR;
    double days=(double)minutes/MINUTES_DAY;

// Print number of mintues, hours, and days
    System.out.printf("%d minutes equal %d hours and equals %.3f days.",   minutes,hours,days);  
  }  
}
```

Comment: `void`, not `Void` in your main method declaration.

Comment: When asking questions you are usually expected to tell us what the error is.  Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask].

Comment: `double days = (double)minutes/MINUTES_DAY` - this will store fractional vaues in `days`. You don't want something like `3.2309` days, do you? Change `double` to `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `Void`. Java is a case-sensitive programming language and you have to take care of capitalization in its keywords. Exchange `Void` with **`void`** and the problem will get solved:)

Comment: `void` with a small v means that the method (in this case `main()`) does not return anything, and this is the only case where you are allowed to write a method that does not have e `return` statement in it. `Void` with a capital V is actual a type in Java (though maybe never used), so Java thinks you want to return something of that type, therefore it doesn’t complain about the capitalization error, but about you not returning the thing you said you would.